# Why is my Apache in an infinite redirection loop?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, httpd.conf

We currently have an internal site set up for IT at `it.example.com`, which hosts a single [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) site.

I want to set up Apache so that if a user goes to `kb.example.com` it redirects them to `http://it.example.com/some/path/to/knowledge-base` as a shortcut.

I added a `<VirtualHost>` at the end of my httpd.conf, and now whenever I try to hit the main site (it.example.com) the browser goes into an infinite redirection loop:

> http://it.example.com/projects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-baseprojects/knowledge-base

Here is my `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.37/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.37
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby
</IfModule>

ServerName it.example.com
ServerAdmin support@example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine-2.4.3/public
ErrorLog logs/redmine_error_log
SetEnv RAILS_ENV production
SetEnv RailsEnv production

#If you are using mod_fcgid and are going to upload files larger than
 #131072 bytes you should consider adding the following line
#that allows to upload files up to 20 mb
MaxRequestLen 20971520

<Directory "/var/www/redmine-2.4.3/public">
    Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName kb.example.com
  Redirect / http://it.example.com/projects/knowledge-base
</VirtualHost>
```

So it looks like the VirtualHost is being ignored and the rules for kb.example.com are ALWAYS in effect - thus causing the infinite redirect...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to wrap your existing `it.example.com` definition in a `<VirtualHost>` block. I think this is being caused because without the vhost definition for `it.example.com`, `kb.example.com` becomes the default vhost. In the event that a suitable vhost isn't found this is what will be served which then comes back to itself ...